# Proper set-up for using import maps with Rails 7 and turbo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo, import-maps

Following an

```
bin/importmap pin pixabay-javascript-autocomplete
```

the `importmap.rb` has the proper entry and the header of the page does have in the script tag for the `imports` json block:

```
"pixabay-javascript-autocomplete": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:pixabay-javascript-autocomplete@1.0.4/auto-complete.min.js",
```

`application.js` was edited with alternately

```
import PixabayJavascriptAutocomplete from "pixabay-javascript-autocomplete"
import Autocomplete from "pixabay-javascript-autocomplete"
```

Yet, on the page where this needs to be fired, nothing happens.
If the script is entered in manually in the erb file, then the script fires as expected (accompanied by a second script which is dependent on the object being invoked)

```
<script>
// JavaScript autoComplete v1.0.4
// https://github.com/Pixabay/JavaScript-autoComplete
[...]
</script>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var demo1 = new autoComplete({
      selector: '#municipal',
      minChars: 1,
      source: function(term, suggest){
          term = term.toLowerCase();
          var choices = <%= raw @municipal_names %>;
          var suggestions = [];
          for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
              if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
          suggest(suggestions);
      }
  });
<% end %>
```

Thus, in practice, the pinned library is not being invoked properly.
How should this be done?

Comment: seems quite a few of these questions, and no answers...